# Is there any plugin for online recording for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any plugin for online webcam recording for wordpress,

User needs to record thier video and needs to upload it to my website.

?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Is+there+any+plugin+for+online+webcam+recording+for+wordpress&oq=Is+there+any+plugin+for+online+webcam+recording+for+wordpress&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.305j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is tool for video/screen shot capture. check it on below url.

URL : http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html

Comment: I requested for wordpress plugin not desktop app